# Paul Erdős Joke.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, notation, recreational-mathematics

I was watching the great documentary "$N$ is a Number" and in it Erdős tells a joke where he writes:

PGOM LD AD LD CD

Which means poor great old man, living dead, archeological discovery, legally dead and counts dead. Which are titles you acquire as you grow older.

My question is if this has something to do with mathematics or its just some random letters.

Regards.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea why the graph at the bottom in [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Paul+Erdos+vs+Euler) has a huge peak in 2013?

Comment: The 'random letters' might be a humorous reference to (honorary) degrees, titles one acquires during the course of one's life as a prolific mathematician: Dr. Soandso, BA, MA, PhD, Dr.Sc, Hon. etc.

Comment: @GitGud, it might have something to do with http://www.google.com/doodles/leonhard-eulers-306th-birthday back in April.

Comment: @BarryCipra Possibly. Follow up question: why is 306 of particular importance?

Comment: @Git Gud - it probably isn't. Google tends to choose some arbitrary anniversaries for events or people. For example, 216 isn't really related to [the first parachute jump](http://www.google.com/doodles/216th-anniversary-of-the-first-parachute-jump), and 153 doesn't have anything to do with [Jane Addams](http://www.google.com/doodles/jane-addams-153rd-birthday)

Comment: @2012ssohn Didn't know that, thanks. They could have at least waited another here since $307$ is a prime number.

Comment: More mysterious, I'd say, is the smaller but nonetheless noticeable peak in the graph for "Erdos" in mid 2009.

Comment: @BarryCipra I didn't notice it was such a recent year, so I assumed it coincided with the publishing of The Man Who Loved Only Numbers, but it does not.

Comment: mabye this has to do: although i don't know if radiolab is popular enough http://www.radiolab.org/story/91699-from-benford-to-erdos/

Comment: @Omnitic Thanks for the link, this is really interesting.

Comment: At 12:55 'It's an Erdös number', 'What's an Erdös?', 'Erdös is a guy.' AHAHAH.

Comment: @Omnitic, as near as I can tell, that RadioLab piece ran toward the end of September, 2009, whereas the Erdos peak in the graph looks to be around the end of May.

Comment: @GitGud: [This BBC video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iflQseSSfA) could be the reason for the peak.